# Is there any way to be notified (email or even SMS) of new comments in a Facebook comment plugin?

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I'd like to subscribe to the updates of the Facebook Comment Plugin:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/

Now I have to go to the website to check the comments from time to time.

Is there any way that I can get notified?

Comment: It doesn't look like there's a way to natively do that. What browser are you using? You could probably write an extension that compares the page's current HTML to a baseline and alerts you if it's changed... not sure if that's worth the effort for you or not.